# Spring Boot Bean Validation No Error Response Returned

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2 project and I'm trying to introduce Bean validation to it.

**My beans are getting validated, but there is no any error response returned.**

I have a POJO annotated like follows

```
@Data
public class AccountSelectBeanRequest implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("accountNo")
@Size(max = 10,message = "maximum length is 10")
private String accountNo;

@JsonProperty("ship-to")
private String shipTo;
```

}

In the resource method I have the @Valid annotation like follows

```
@PostMapping("/account-select")
public ResponseEntity<?> selectAccount(@Valid @RequestBody  AccountSelectBeanRequest accountRequest) {...}
```

When I call the `selectAccount` method with a `accountNo` larger than 10, I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request with an **empty response body**.

**But if I validate a request parameter in a resource method like follows, it returns an error response body as expected.**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/generate-token")
public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam @NotNull @NotEmpty String password)
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?

POM dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Binding for Log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a controller advice to intercept the bad request status and return a custom response message.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class validationAdvice{

    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> methodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();

        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

        String errorMessage = fieldErrors.get(0).getDefaultMessage();

        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
    }

}
```